Proving that $f: T\to S$ factors through $V$ if and only if $f^{*}(v) = 0$ ( for some representable functor )
First note next Proposition ( Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book ):

Proposition 8.4. Let $S$ be a scheme and let $v: \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F}$ be a homomorphism of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be finite locally free. Then the locus $v=0$ is closed ; i.e., theh functor
$$ F : (\operatorname{Sch}/S)^{\operatorname{opp}} \to (\operatorname{Set}), \ F(T) := \{ f\in \operatorname{Hom}_S(T,S) ; f^{*}(v)=0 \}$$
is represented by a closed subscheme $V$ of $S$ ; that is, there exist an natural isomorphism $\eta : h_V \to F$.

Accepting this propostion, I am trying to show that "a morphism $ f: T\to S$ factors through $V$ if and only if $f^{*}(v) =0$." 'If  ' direction can be showed since if $f^{*}(v)=0$, then we may consider $(\eta_T)^{-1}(f)$. And I still don't know how can we show the 'only if' direction.

What you want to show seems to be the very definition of $V$. What is the problem?

O.K. After some consideration, it is helpful to note that for an $S$-scheme $T$, the set $\operatorname{Hom}_S(T,S)$ is a singleton set and therefore $F(T)$ above question has at most one element. If $f : T \to S$ factors through $V$ so that there exists $l : T \to V$ such that $f = h \circ l$ where $ h : V \hookrightarrow X$, then $\eta_T (l) = f$ and $f^{}(v) = (\eta_T (l))^{}(v) = 0$ !
